# Oracle: One attribute with date, another with date and time?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am taking an introductory course to databases so I am a complete beginner. In the database I am supposed to create I have two tables, each contain a DATE datatype.

In the first table, I want it to only display a date (DD-MM-YY) and in the second table display a date and time (DD-MM-YY HH24:MM).

How can I format each attribute to have these respective formats? I've looked around and tried the following command:

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

Which works nicely for the date and time field but leaves 00:00:00 for the date only field. Which I do not want, so I reverted it back to nls_date_format = 'DD-MM-YY'

As of right now the following:

```
INSERT INTO ITEM (ITEM_ENDDATEANDTIME)
VALUES ('13-AUG-13 23:56:00');
```

Gives me the error: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Any ideas? Again, I'm a beginner a lot of this is new to me! Thanks!

Comment: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2012/06/22/date-is-not-a-date/

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is always store your date values **as dates**. Data manipulation is infinitely easier when you have stored them in this format instead of in a text based format.

Then, you output them into a more human readable format through a query using syntax similar to this:

```
SELECT DateField,
       TO_CHAR(DateField, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS Date1,
       TO_CHAR(Datefield, 'DD-MM-YY') AS Date2
FROM MyTable
```

This takes the date data and outputs it as a formatted string. I hope this helps.

Comment: So, I should basically just ignore the 00:00:00 and use the to_char statement on retrieval to truncate the irrelevant timestamp?

Comment: Yep. As long as the data is truly stored as a date, you can retrieve it and display it in whatever form you want.